# Why echo dont show my string?

Tags: php, string, function

I was learned java, but i want to try some php...
Tell me is that can work?

```
public function Say_Hi(){
    echo "Hi boss!";
}
$ZiennaMetoda=Say_Hi();

echo $ZiennaMetoda;
```

Comment: You probably need `return "Hi boss!"`.

Comment: If you are interested in learning PHP, then you should follow some tutorials: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php

Comment: `Learned JAVA` ? what do you mean

Comment: thanks for link to codeacademy :)

Comment: @Naveen - I suspect that OP means `learned JavaScript`, not Java.... if he was familiar with Java, he'd probably understand not to echo in a function/method, but to return instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function cannot be public unless it is part of a class. Remove that keyword and it works.

Although I shall add that your code is a bit confusing. You will either want to have a function that prints something or a function that returns something and is assigned to a variable. You're doing a mix of the two. As suggested otherwise, I would recommend replacing the 'echo' with a 'return'.